# linked dropdown menus with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need two drop down menus. The first has options equipment1, equipment2, equipment 3 and equipment 4. When an option is selected, a second dropdown should appear with ten options from parameter1 to parameter10. When one of these are chosen, a text box and submit button must appear and also, the parameter value should be passed to a database. How can we do this using ajax? Is this possible? If so, how? I'm very new to Ajax so please go slow and answer clearly. Thanks!

Comment: so, what do you have already, and with what part of the code we can help you. You seem to want a specific answer, for a very unspecific unclear question...

Comment: I can do the above without ajax but it is essential i add ajax and i don't know where and how to add it

Comment: here are examples of how to use ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @RaviTej310 Can you show us your code?

Comment: You might want to try this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample about AJAX call with Jquery. Hope this help ^^

```js
$.ajax({
        url: /*url to server file(.php/.aspx) pass value to database*/,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: 'textboxvalue=' + /*value from your textbox. ex: $('#txtInput').val()*/,
        success: function(res) {
            /*If connect success and server work successfully, what you want to do here*/
            
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Connection error");
            return;
        }
    });
```